# C++ includes acting funny Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, include

I'm trying to write a neural net in C++, and in one of the header files I'm trying to write, there's an issue with the an include at the top. When I double click the include in Eclipse's outline for the file, it takes me to the write one, so Eclipse knows it's there, but the compiler keeps complaining it isn't. The directory looks something like this (I cut out all files that had nothing to do with the problem):

```
src
->Layers
  -->Layer.h
->Neurons
  -->Neuron.h
->main.cpp
```

The Layers.h file code is below:

```
#ifndef LAYERS_LAYER_H_
#define LAYERS_LAYER_H_
#include <vector>
#include "../src/Neurons/Neuron.h"

class Layer{
public:
    std::vector<Neuron> layer;
    Layer(Neuron a, int n){
        layer = std::vector<Neuron>(n);
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            layer[i] = a;
        }
    }
    virtual std::vector<double> fire(std::vector<double>);
    virtual std::vector<double> fire();
    virtual std::vector<double> derivative(std::vector<double>);
    virtual std::vector<double> derivative();
    virtual ~Layer(){}
};



#endif /* LAYERS_LAYER_H_ */
```

and the line with #include "../src/Neurons/Neuron.h" gives the error

```
In file included from ..\src\Layers\Layer.cpp:7:0:
..\src\Layers\Layer.h:11:10: fatal error: ../src/Neurons/Neuron.h: No such file or directory
 #include "../src/Neurons/Neuron.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've been able to include the file in main.cpp and it works fine.

Comment: Should that be `../../src/Neurons/Neurons.h` or `../Neurons/Neuron.h`? Looks like you're off by one directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "../src/Neurons/Neuron.h"` tells compiler to go up one level in hierarchy of directories relative to current file location. So `../` would be already inside of `src` and there is no need to add `/src`. So your include should look like:

```
#include "../Neurons/Neuron.h"
```

Comment: That worked, I didn't realize that "../" moved up a directory. I assumed it was the root directory or something like that. Thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.